# Tkinter wait for tcp input/output

Tags: python, user-interface, tcp, event-handling, tkinter

I wrote a networked chatroom server and client and it works in a simple Terminal environment just fin, and just today started to translate it to over to a GUI form using Tkinter. The sending of messages is fine as I can handle them with button press event handlers and  key handles, but the problem is receiving messages. I need to be able to check to see if data has been received while still in the Tkinter window. Is there a nice way of doing something like this? I've tried checking every second using the root.action(time,event) call, but that didn't seem to work, and have just tried running loops in different spots (against my better judgement).

What can I do to have Tkinter listen to something outside of itself, but still be listening to the events going on within my Tkinter window?

Answer (score 1):

See

[How do you run your own code alongside Tkinter's event loop?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/459083/how-do-you-run-your-own-code-alongside-tkinters-event-loop/1835036#1835036)

In particular, the comment about setting the timeout to 0 in the Tk().after() call, so you have non-blocking, *outside the Tk event loop* code handling possibilities.

Hope that helps.

Comment: This didn't work well, the program would lock up a lot. :-/ But it did work for very select amounts of time

Comment: Yeah, it'll be voodoo ridden code flow management to be trustworthy.  *(by that I mean knowledge base)*